# MS ACCESS query using form to build WHERE clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need to be able to read a combo box to determine to column to use for a where clause.
Simple example would be
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [Forms]![frmNameWhatever]![ComboTime] BETWEEN [blah]![blah]![blah] AND [blah]![blah]![blah]

blah blah blah works... The first part, right after the where, returns zero rows...
Am i using the wrong syntax? 
I've tried this w/ a text box as well and it still returns zero rows...
Sorry someone might have to re-write this but i'm tired.. its the end of the day

Thanks for any help ^^

Comment: What does blah!blah!blah represent?  Are those more controls on your form?

Comment: Yes, I will edit this. However, the blah!blah!blah was the part that worked, right after the WHERE keyword, needs to be "dynamic". I want to know if its possible In Access, to change this to be something that is dependent on what is selected inside a combo box

Answer (score 1):

Try putting pound signs around your BETWEEN values.

```
BETWEEN #8:00 AM# and #12:00 PM#
```

To create a dynamic SQL string:

```
strSQL = _
   "Select myColumns FROM myTable WHERE " & Me.myComboBox & " BETWEEN #" & _
   Me.MyFirstTextBoxDate & "# AND #" & Me.MySecondTextBoxDate & "#"
```

Comment: the between values work perfectly. but, right after the WHERE keyword, needs to be "dynamic". I want to know if its possible In Access, to change this to be something that is dependent on what is selected inside a combo box

Comment: I'll try this, but I got a feeling you're misinterpreting my problem. In your example, I need "myDateColumn" to come from a value in a combo box, the value in the combo box will say a column in the table. so, WHERE [comboxboxvalue] BETWEEN [textboxdate] AND [textboxdate]

Comment: I made the edit, but of course, now you need a way to execute it.  Is this string going into the DataSource of a subform, or something similar?

Comment: hmm, I see your using vba... i was using the sql form of the query designer... I was trying to avoid alot of work..

Comment: You can set conditions based on form controls in the query designer, but I don't believe you can specify columns dynamically in this way. If you try, you will get the value of the form control as the column output, not the value of the table column.

Comment: You still haven't said what you're using the output of the query for.  If it's for a subform, you can simply put the SQL string I gave you into the DataSource property of the subform.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate an sql statement and run it with RunSQL like so:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL("(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE " & Forms("frmNameWhatever").ComboTime.Value & " BETWEEN [blah]![blah]![blah] AND [blah]![blah]![blah]);")
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a good idea to hard code your Form's control names within your SQL code. Consider a `PROCEDURE` with strongly-typed parameters e.g. [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HP030704831033.aspx) syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOrdersByPeriod
(
 :start_date DATETIME, 
 :end_date DATETIME
)
AS 
SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate
  FROM Orders
 WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date;
```

You would then `EXECUTE` this proc by passing in your controls' values as parameters.

Comment: my problem is the "item" (in ur example it would be OrderDate) right after the WHERE keyword, needs to be "dynamic". I want to know if its possible In Access, to change this to be something that is dependent on what is selected inside a combo box

Comment: So have multiple procs -- GetOrderByOrderDate, GetOrderByRequiredDate, GetOrderByShippedDate, etc -- then use your combobox's value to 'dynamically' choose the required proc.